# why does value allocated in stack didn't result in double free pointer?

Tags: rust

Please tell me why didn't result in double free pointer that the value is allocated in stack? Thanks.

```rust
#[test]
fn read_value_that_allocated_in_stack_is_no_problem() {
    let origin = Value(1);
    let copied = unsafe { std::ptr::read(&origin) };

    assert_eq!(copied, Value(1));
    assert_eq!(copied, origin);
}

/// test failed as expected: double free detected
#[test]
fn read_value_that_allocated_in_heap_will_result_in_double_free_problem() {
    let origin = Box::new(Value(1));
    let copied = unsafe { std::ptr::read(&origin) };

    assert_eq!(copied, Box::new(Value(1)));
    assert_eq!(copied, origin);
}


#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Value<T>(T);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unsafe method you are using just creates a bitwise copy of the referenced value. When you do this with a `Box`, it's not okay but for something like your `Value` struct containing an integer, it is okay to make the copy as `Drop` of integers has no side effects while `drop` of `Box` accesses global allocator and changes the state.

*If you do not understand any term I used for this explanation, try to search it or ask in the comments.*

Answer (score 2):

Those tests hide the fact that you use different types in them. It isn't really about stack or heap.

1. In the first one you use `Value<i32>` type, which is your custom type, presumably without custom `Drop` implemented. If so, then Rust will call `Drop` on each member, in this case the `i32` member. Which does nothing. And so nothing happens when both objects go out of scope. Even if you implement `Drop`, it would have to have some serious side-effects (like call to free) for it to fail.
2. In the second one you actually use `Box` type, which does implement `Drop`. Internally it calls free (in addition to dropping the underlying object). And so free is called twice on drop, trying to free the same pointer (because of the unsafe copy).

Comment: Thanks very much, I have tried just now, even if I implement `Drop` for `Value` is no problem. the actual problem is when a type implements `Drop` that deallocate memory will result in double free problem.

Comment: @holi-java I'm not sure I understand you. Where did I say that implementing `Drop` for `Value` would change anything? The reason your second test fails, is because the concrete implementation of `Drop` on `Box` fails, when used unsafely.

Comment: @holi-java Where did I said that implementing `Drop` on `Value` will make the first test fail? On the contrary, it is guaranteed that `Drop` with no side-effects will not make the test fail. I've updated the answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a double free because we do not free the memory twice. Because we do not free memory at all.

However, whether this is *valid* or UB is another question. Miri does not flag it as UB, however Miri does not aim to flag any UB out there. If `Value<i32>` was `Copy`, that would be fine. As it is not, it depends on the question whether `std::ptr::read()` invalidates the original data, i.e. is it always invalid to use a data that was `std::ptr::read()`'ed, or only if it violates Stacked Borrows semantics, like in the case of copying the `Box` itself where both destructors try to access the `Box` thereafter?

The answer is that it's not decided yet. As per [UCG issue #307, "Are `Copy` implementations semantically relevant (besides specialization)?"](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/307#issuecomment-979591380):

**@steffahn**

> Overall, this still being an open question means that while miri doesn't complain, one should avoid code like this because it's not yet certain that it *won't* be UB, right?

**@RalfJung**

> Yes.

In conclusion, you should avoid code like that.

Comment: Thanks, `ptr::read` does not care the value is-a `Copy`, rather the copied value shares the same memory region that will make the memory deallocated twice.

Comment: @holi-java Nope. Double-free only refers to heap-allocated memory.

Comment: @holi-java What do you mean by "`ptr::read` does not care the value is-a `Copy`"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are totally right, but smart pointers maybe take the value in heap, I think `ptr::read` method is just share the same bytes in memory as database view, and then reflect the type of the value. there are two pointers point the same same memory after `ptr::read` which will double free the same memory at end.

Comment: if we use `Value<String>` in the first test, the test will also failed. since the `String` struct also allocates the memory in heap.

Comment: `ptr::read()` performs a bitwise copy. That's it. What will be the results strongly depends on the types involved.

Comment: You corrected me, thanks.  the heap memory is also not shared. `ptr::read` is just like the behavior of the c `memcpy` function. but why `ptr::read(&String)` will results in double free problem?

Comment: here is the [test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ecc39094eca9427c86c632369cfc71e6).

Comment: @holi-java Because `String`, just like `Box`, contains a pointer to heap-allocated data (in fact, `String` is just a wrapper around `Vec<u8>`).

Comment: Hi, but the copied `String`  with the different `Vec<u8>` except their content sare the same. why did `ptr::read` will result in double free?

Comment: No. They share the buffer. `ptr::read()` does a **bitwise** copy, not deep copy.

Comment: sir, you mean the bitwise copy operation does not do deep copy? but I found they have the different buffers in [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a13ed65ea9eb33856f7207fbc6bb82f).

Comment: Your test is not correct. You overwrote _the whole string_, not the buffer. [This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=22116893b2490f9d892abc7fc564e427) is a correct test that shows they do share the same buffer.

Comment: sir, even if I used `Vec` directly, `ptr::read` also have [different buffers](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8a18cffee4db4d0e860808d22a2ba90). I get to confused...

Comment: Same reasoing. You're overwriting the vec, not its buffer. It allocates a new buffer. It's the same as doing `copied = vec![2];`, except it doesn't drop the old value.

Comment: You are right. I found the pointer and memory is not simple for me...

Comment: Rust is not simple. Just do not write unsafe code and everything will be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much. and I found bitwise just copy the pointer & primitives rather than the data that the pointer point to? Am I right, sir?

Comment: Yes. More technically, it doesn't follow pointers, i.e. a kind of shallow copy.

Comment: @holi-java Had you serially upvoted my other answers? Please don't do that. It's [forbidden](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and will also not help me as the votes will be cancelled automatically. It may only cause harm to you. If this answer is helpful, upvote it and only it.

Comment: Thank you, but this is again StackOverflow rules, and like I said, will not help me either (and my put your account in suspension).